# Acces to WPF value though proxy in code

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, proxy

I am quite a beginner in WPF.

It is about data binding, on a 3D object defined using the Helix ToolKit. 
The point is that the object which is used do not derive from `FrameworkElement`, so I get the error at runtime :

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element.

I rely on [this blog](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) for the solution of my problem.

My question, according to this post, is how can I set the value of the data from the code ? Do I have to instantiate the proxy, or is there a tricky thing I miss ?

Any help greatly appreciated !

Comment: Show your specific problem and what you tried already

Comment: dataGrid.Columns[0].Binding = new Binding(whatever) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this question was down-voted, I guess it wasn't so clear...

Actually I was mistaken, I don't need to access the proxy instance in code.

In the ViewModel I declare the data variable `DataViewModel`, and in the XAML I set the proxy variable `DataProxy` using the ViewModel value, by doing :

```
<Proxy x:Key="proxyKey" DataProxy="{Binding DataViewModel}" />
```

And to set the value `Data3D`to the 3D object, I do as in the blog :

```
<Object3D Data3D="{Binding DataProxy, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=proxyKey}}"
```

The Header of the view declares the `DataContext`referencing the ViewModel. And in the code of the ViewModel, I can access the property `DataViewModel` to define its value. The property `DataViewModel` is defined in the ViewModel so that it can be bound to the View.

It works, no more errors...